# Can't get a RoR project to work in production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have a problem with the setup of a new rails project. It works fine in development mode but crash in production. Here is what I mean.

I have just one controller with a single method which are generated with rails

```
rails g controller Products list
```

So far so good. When I type `http://localhost:3000/products/list` I get the default message from the view. 
When I change the RAILS_ENV to production restart the server and reload the page I get an error  `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

Here is the content of production.log

```
I, [2014-08-10T19:46:24.483309 #4333]  INFO -- : Started GET "/products/list/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-10 19:46:24 +0300
I, [2014-08-10T19:46:24.484491 #4333]  INFO -- : Processing by ProductsController#list as HTML
I, [2014-08-10T19:46:24.485243 #4333]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
F, [2014-08-10T19:46:24.489038 #4333] FATAL -- :
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String):
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:21:in `pbkdf2_hmac_sha1'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:21:in `generate_key'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:38:in `generate_key'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:509:in `initialize'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:160:in `new'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:160:in `encrypted'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:169:in `signed_or_encrypted'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:119:in `cookie_jar'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:114:in `get_cookie'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:90:in `block in unpacked_cookie_data'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `stale_session_check!'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:89:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:83:in `block in extract_session_id'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `stale_session_check!'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:82:in `extract_session_id'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:49:in `block in []'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:48:in `fetch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:48:in `[]'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:70:in `id'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:282:in `current_session_id'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:288:in `session_exists?'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:152:in `exists?'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:172:in `load_for_read!'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:89:in `[]'
  turbolinks (2.2.2) lib/turbolinks/xhr_headers.rb:35:in `set_xhr_redirected_to'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

I use Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 4.1.4 + rvm for ruby managment

Comment: there is no way anyone can answer your question due to absolute lack of info you provide.

Comment: What else should I provide? I described all the steps I did.

Comment: could you update the question with the `database.yml` file?

Comment: Update your question with the code of `ProductsController#list` action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `config/secrets.yml` does not have an entry for the production environment (or the entry is misconfigured).

```
production:
  secret_key_base: 527dacc0390e10df59278f1a18aa8ad14e429fa6ce522e5fb3b7ac358007dff4
```

Don't use the key posted here. You can generate a new one with a rake task and paste it into your `config/secrets.yml` file

```
bundle exec rake secrets
```

Comment: It had but was short.